# Python Librosa : What is the default frame size used to compute the MFCC features?

Tags: python-3.x, audio, mfcc

Using Librosa library, I generated the MFCC features of audio file 1319 seconds into a matrix `20 X 56829`. The `20` here represents the no of MFCC features (Which I can manually adjust it). But I don't know how it segmented the audio length into `56829`. What is the frame size it takes process the audio?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import librosa

def getPathToGroundtruth(episode):
    """Return path to groundtruth file for episode"""
    pathToGroundtruth = "../../../season01/Audio/" \
                        + "Season01.Episode%02d.en.wav" % episode
    return pathToGroundtruth

def getduration(episode):
    pathToAudioFile = getPathToGroundtruth(episode)
    y, sr = librosa.load(pathToAudioFile)
    duration = librosa.get_duration(y=y, sr=sr)
    return duration
def getMFCC(episode):
    filename = getPathToGroundtruth(episode)
    y, sr = librosa.load(filename)  # Y gives 
    data = librosa.feature.mfcc(y=y, sr=sr)
    return data


data = getMFCC(1)
```

Comment: could you provide code you used?

Comment: updated the question with the code

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Short Answer**

You can specify the change the length by changing the parameters used in the stft calculations. The following code will double the size of your output (20 x 113658)

```
data = librosa.feature.mfcc(y=y, sr=sr, n_fft=1012, hop_length=256, n_mfcc=20)
```

**Long Answer**

Librosa's `librosa.feature.mfcc()` function really just acts as a wrapper to  librosa's `librosa.feature.melspectrogram()` function (which is a wrapper to `librosa.core.stft` and `librosa.filters.mel` functions).

All of the parameters pertaining to segementation of the audio signal - namely the frame and overlap values - are specified utilized in the Mel-scaled power spectrogram function (with other tune-able parameters specified for nested core functions). You specify these parameters as keyword arguments in the `librosa.feature.mfcc()` function.

All extra `**kwargs` parameters are fed to `librosa.feature.melspectrogram()` and subsequently to `librosa.filters.mel()`

By Default, the Mel-scaled power spectrogram window and hop length are the following:

`n_fft=2048`

`hop_length=512`

So assuming you used the default sample rate (`sr=22050`), the output of your mfcc function makes sense:

output length = *(seconds) * (sample rate) / (hop_length)*

*(1319) * (22050) / (512)* = **56804** samples

The parameters that you are able to tune, are the following:

```
Melspectrogram Parameters
-------------------------
y : np.ndarray [shape=(n,)] or None
    audio time-series

sr : number > 0 [scalar]
    sampling rate of `y`

S : np.ndarray [shape=(d, t)]
    power spectrogram

n_fft : int > 0 [scalar]
    length of the FFT window

hop_length : int > 0 [scalar]
    number of samples between successive frames.
    See `librosa.core.stft`

kwargs : additional keyword arguments
  Mel filter bank parameters.
  See `librosa.filters.mel` for details.
```

If you want to further specify characteristics of the mel filterbank used to define the Mel-scaled power spectrogram, you can tune the following

```
Mel Frequency Parameters
------------------------
sr        : number > 0 [scalar]
    sampling rate of the incoming signal

n_fft     : int > 0 [scalar]
    number of FFT components

n_mels    : int > 0 [scalar]
    number of Mel bands to generate

fmin      : float >= 0 [scalar]
    lowest frequency (in Hz)

fmax      : float >= 0 [scalar]
    highest frequency (in Hz).
    If `None`, use `fmax = sr / 2.0`

htk       : bool [scalar]
    use HTK formula instead of Slaney
```

Documentation for Librosa:

[librosa.feature.melspectrogram](http://librosa.github.io/librosa/generated/librosa.feature.melspectrogram.html#librosa.feature.melspectrogram)

[librosa.filters.mel](http://librosa.github.io/librosa/generated/librosa.filters.mel.html#librosa.filters.mel)

[librosa.core.stft](http://librosa.github.io/librosa/generated/librosa.core.stft.html#librosa.core.stft)